# Download text file from website using WebCLient

Tags: c#, web, webclient

We recently switched our ftp site at work from ftp://address to https://ftp.address and now my application that retrieves files is unable to download files with expected content.

I previously used FtpWebRequest and it has been working for many years.
I am now trying to use WebClient and it downloads a file but it is not the text file I need. Instead, the contents of the file turns out to be some HTML.

Previous that worked:

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(getAppSetting("URI") + getAppSetting("FilePath") + args[0].ToString());

request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

setCredentials(request);

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Changed code to handle https:

System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

WebClient request = new WebClient();                  

setCredentials(request);

string file = request.DownloadString(getAppSetting("URI") + getAppSetting("FilePath") + args[0].ToString());
```

The result is a file that is downloaded but it contains HTML. I expect to have the contents of the file on the website I am pulling from.

Comment: Are you sure the server is sending a 'https' response? May be it still sends a 'ftp' response?

Comment: Have you read the contents of the HTML?   It's probably a standard web page saying the content can't be found.

Comment: Poul, how can I tell what the response is? the WebClient does not have a definition for 'GetResponse'. Am I using the class to retrieve data?

Comment: Neil, this is some of the current content of the file:  
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

Answer (score 1):

After a couple of weeks of research, I finally found out what I needed to do and the answer was quite simple. I found out that our new website uses SSH so I installed SSH.Net via my nugent package to Visual Studio, and added "using Renci.SshNet;". I used the following code to download the file to my local drive:

```
using (SftpClient sftp = new SftpClient("ftp.website.com", 22,"username", "password")
{
   sftp.Connect();

   if (sftp.IsConnected)
   {
     using (Filestream fs = new FileStream("Output.txt", FileMode.Create))
      {
        sftp.DownloadFile("/file/Client/Input.txt", fs);
      }
   } 

   sftp.Disconnect();
 }
```

This works perfectly. My file no longer downloads as an HTML file and I get my desired output. I hope this saves someone else a lot of time.